# Generic function to Spary JSON data types, throws type mismatch error

Tags: scala, generics, spray-json

I'm using [spray-json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) and I need to parse the given request body (`PATCH, POST`), request body attributes can have following possibilities represented by `Either[Unit.type, Option[A]]`

- `value` Not given `Left[Unit.type]`
- `value=null` Null  `Right[None]`
- `value=XXX` Some value is provided `Right[Some(value)]`

Using the above possibilities I need to create a entity from the request body. While parsing I need to validate each field with some business logic (String length, integer range ...).

I have a following function for the business logic validation.

```
def validateValue[T](fieldName: String,
                     maybeValue: Try[T],
                     businessValidation: T => Boolean): Option[T] = {
  maybeValue match {
    case Success(value) if businessValidation(value) => Some(value)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Similarly another function `readFieldWithValidation`, here I will be parsing each attribute based on the input type and apply the business validation.

```
def readFieldWithValidation[S, T](fields: Map[String, JsValue], fieldName: String, businessValidation: T => Boolean)(
  parse: S => T
): Option[T] = {
  fields.get(fieldName) match {
    case None => None
    case Some(jsValue) =>
      jsValue match {
        case jsString: JsString =>
          validateValue(fieldName, Try(parse(jsString.value)), businessValidation)
        case JsNumber(jsNumber) =>
          validateValue(fieldName, Try(parse(jsNumber.intValue)), businessValidation)
        case _ => None
      }
  }
}
```

I have `S ( Source )` and `T ( Target )` which is used for given a `JsValue` returns `T` type. Here I only care about `JsString` and `JsNumber`.

The above lines of code is giving `type mismatch` error,

> ```
> <console>:112: error: type mismatch;
>  found   : jsString.value.type (with underlying type String)
>  required: S
>                  validateValue(fieldName, Try(parse(jsString.value)), businessValidation)
>                                                              ^
> <console>:114: error: type mismatch;
>  found   : Int
>  required: S
>                  validateValue(fieldName, Try(parse(jsNumber.intValue)), businessValidation)
> ```

Can someone help me how to overcome this error?

This is how I can use above function

```
val attributes = Map("String" -> JsString("ThisIsString"), "Int" -> JsNumber(23)) 

def stringLengthConstraint(min: Int, max: Int)(value: String) = value.length > min && value.length < max 

readFieldWithValidation[JsString, String](attributes, "String", stringLengthConstraint(1, 10))(_.toString)
```

Comment: Your expected usage scenarios are not clear from the code you provided. Could you please elaborate your question with more examples of hypothetical usages? For example, why do you need `parse` at all? Why `parse` and `businessValidation` are separate entities? Why `businessValidation` happens after `parse`? Is `businessValidation` expected to be a single function specifically selected fro given `fieldName` and `parse` or is it a bunch of generic validation rules and the appropriate one should be somehow magically auto-chosen by type?

Comment: @SergGr updated. Let me know, if you still miss information.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is still not quite clear because it does not show the role of `parse` and actually looks contradictory to the other code: particularly you specify the generic parameter `S` as `JsString` in `readFieldWithValidation[JsString, String]` but given current (borken) `readFieldWithValidation` implementation your `parse` argument is probably expected to be of type `String => String` because `jsString.value` is `String`.

Anyway here is a piece of code that seem to implement something that is hopefully sufficiently close to what you want:

```
trait JsValueExtractor[T] {
  def getValue(jsValue: JsValue): Option[T]
}

object JsValueExtractor {
  implicit val decimalExtractor = new JsValueExtractor[BigDecimal] {
    override def getValue(jsValue: JsValue) = jsValue match {
      case JsNumber(jsNumber) => Some(jsNumber)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
  implicit val intExtractor = new JsValueExtractor[Int] {
    override def getValue(jsValue: JsValue) = jsValue match {
      case JsNumber(jsNumber) => Some(jsNumber.intValue)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
  implicit val doubleExtractor = new JsValueExtractor[Double] {
    override def getValue(jsValue: JsValue) = jsValue match {
      case JsNumber(jsNumber) => Some(jsNumber.doubleValue)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
  implicit val stringExtractor = new JsValueExtractor[String] {
    override def getValue(jsValue: JsValue) = jsValue match {
      case JsString(string) => Some(string)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}


def readFieldWithValidation[S, T](fields: Map[String, JsValue], fieldName: String, businessValidation: T => Boolean)(parse: S => T)(implicit valueExtractor: JsValueExtractor[S]) = {
  fields.get(fieldName)
    .flatMap(jsValue => valueExtractor.getValue(jsValue))
    .flatMap(rawValue => Try(parse(rawValue)).toOption)
    .filter(businessValidation)
}
```

and usage example:

```
def test(): Unit = {
  val attributes = Map("String" -> JsString("ThisIsString"), "Int" -> JsNumber(23))

  def stringLengthConstraint(min: Int, max: Int)(value: String) = value.length > min && value.length < max

  val value = readFieldWithValidation[String, String](attributes, "String", stringLengthConstraint(1, 10))(identity)
  println(value)
}
```

Your current code uses `Option[T]` as your return type. If I were using a code like this I'd probably added some error logging and/or handling for a case where the code contains a bug and `attributes` do contain a value for key `fieldName` but of some different, unexpected type (like `JsNumber` instead of `JsString`).

---

## Update

It is not clear from your comment whether you are satisfied with my original answer or want to add some error handling. If you want to report the type mismatch errors, and since you are using cats, something like `ValidatedNel` is an obvious choice:

```
type ValidationResult[A] = ValidatedNel[String, A]

trait JsValueExtractor[T] {
  def getValue(jsValue: JsValue, fieldName: String): ValidationResult[T]
}


object JsValueExtractor {
  implicit val decimalExtractor = new JsValueExtractor[BigDecimal] {
    override def getValue(jsValue: JsValue, fieldName: String): ValidationResult[BigDecimal] = jsValue match {
      case JsNumber(jsNumber) => jsNumber.validNel
      case _ => s"Field '$fieldName' is expected to be decimal".invalidNel
    }
  }
  implicit val intExtractor = new JsValueExtractor[Int] {
    override def getValue(jsValue: JsValue, fieldName: String): ValidationResult[Int] = jsValue match {
      case JsNumber(jsNumber) => Try(jsNumber.toIntExact) match {
        case scala.util.Success(intValue) => intValue.validNel
        case scala.util.Failure(e) => s"Field $fieldName is expected to be int".invalidNel
      }
      case _ => s"Field '$fieldName' is expected to be int".invalidNel
    }
  }
  implicit val doubleExtractor = new JsValueExtractor[Double] {
    override def getValue(jsValue: JsValue, fieldName: String): ValidationResult[Double] = jsValue match {
      case JsNumber(jsNumber) => jsNumber.doubleValue.validNel
      case _ => s"Field '$fieldName' is expected to be double".invalidNel
    }
  }
  implicit val stringExtractor = new JsValueExtractor[String] {
    override def getValue(jsValue: JsValue, fieldName: String): ValidationResult[String] = jsValue match {
      case JsString(string) => string.validNel
      case _ => s"Field '$fieldName' is expected to be string".invalidNel
    }
  }
}


def readFieldWithValidation[S, T](fields: Map[String, JsValue], fieldName: String, businessValidation: T => Boolean)
                                 (parse: S => T)(implicit valueExtractor: JsValueExtractor[S]): ValidationResult[T] = {

  fields.get(fieldName) match {
    case None => s"Field '$fieldName' is required".invalidNel
    case Some(jsValue) => valueExtractor.getValue(jsValue, fieldName)
        .andThen(rawValue => Try(parse(rawValue).validNel).getOrElse("".invalidNel))
        .andThen(parsedValue => if (businessValidation(parsedValue)) parsedValue.validNel else s"Business validation for field '$fieldName' has failed".invalidNel)
  }

}
```

And the `test` example remains the same. Probably in your real code you want to use something more specific than just `String` for errors but that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. I was using `cats` in actual implementation like `Object.mapN(attributes)`. I was able to handle, parse and validate given request body, but I was failing to handle `unexpected type` (mentioned above).  Hence I introduce `S` type, where this problem became even more tougher.

Comment: @PuneethReddyV, It is not clear from your comment whether you are satisfied with my original answer or want to add some error handling. I updated my answer with one that uses cats `ValidatedNel` for error reporting